# What is this connector? Round 8 pins, 5 notches on metal shell

Tags: connector, identification

I'm looking at the output connector of a Lambda TCR600S1 power supply.  It looks like this:

[image]

This has 8 pins and a metal shell with 5 notches on the inside, and what looks like some locking pins on the outside.  It is supposed to be rated to high voltages (>600V).  What is it?

(Unfortunately I have no documentation for this power suppply.  I've used Lambda power supplies before, they usually come with screw terminals)

Comment: i deleted my other comments ... this is the closest (male version) ... https://www.bmisurplus.com/products/51365-bendix-pt02h-12-8p-connector  so yours is a `Bendix PT02H-12-8S`

Comment: http://www.amphenol-aerospace.com/pdf/12-070.pdf  page 16

Comment: from what i can tell the connector and the metal shell are two separate parts. the metal part is a "holder" and the connector is a cable end.

Comment: @jsotola Thank you! Yes, that looks like it.  Post as an answer so I can accept and upvote :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is the closest (male version)

https://www.bmisurplus.com/products/51365-bendix-pt02h-12-8p-connector

so yours is a Bendix PT02H-12-8S

from what i can tell the connector and the metal shell are two separate parts.

the metal part is a "holder" and the connector is a cable end.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't look unlike connectors made by the British Company Plessey.  That were widely used on military aircraft back in the 1960's and later.